# Mysql Error Issue When Insert Query Is Run

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form. After submit the form it's show following error message:

**Error Message:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'm ok. ', 'point of interest', 
'91354857', '6546564654', '2 Person', '25', 'engl' at line 1
```

**Mysql Query:**

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO host_signup VALUES('', '$uname', '$f_name', 
'$pr_lname', '$email', '$hashpass', '$title', '$country', '$city', '$state', 
'$postalcode', '$address', '$final_neighbor', '$landline', '$mobileph', '$capacity', 
'$age', '$language', '$final_interest', '$news', '$ip', '$dof', '0' )");
```

Actually it's show the error message when I put `stripslashes()` in the variable But without `stripslashes()` it's show backslashes.

For example:

```
$address = $_POST['address'];       
$address = stripslashes($address);
```

Comment: Do any of the variables have single quotes in them? Note: Your query is subject to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Do all of your columns take strings? If the db is in strict mode it will reject numbers surrounded by quotes for int columns.

Comment: For avoiding this kind of silly errors start using `prepared statement` in `mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Comment: @Sepster Mysql Columns is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your sql values before putting them in a query. looks like one of your strings had a `'` and mysql cut that? I'm guessing that `'m ok. '` is the end of "i'm ok.".

That string should be `i\'m ok.`.

Comment: run `$address = addslashes($address)` before you put those variables in your query.

Comment: @AlexMojum use `addslashes`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addslashes`.

> `addslashes` — Quote string with slashes

#### [`Official Document`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

**Example**

```
<?php
  $str = "Is your name O'reilly?";
  // Outputs: Is your name O\'reilly?
  echo addslashes($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) -- *not* `addslashes()`, as suggested by others

The [`addslashes()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) concurs:

> It's highly recommended to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL), but if the DBMS you're using doesn't have an escape function and the DBMS uses \ to escape special chars, you can use this function.